# Error while retrieving data from firebase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i have completed the Google sign-in option but when im not able to retrieve the details of the google account registered.

Here's my code:

There's some problem with credential parameter,below is the screenshot of my problem[image]

```
Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  String name;
  String email;
  String imageUrl;
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
  print("signed in " + user.displayName);
  return user;


//  final FirebaseUser userDetails =
//  (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
//// Add the following lines after getting the user
//// Checking if email and name is null
//  assert(userDetails.email != null);
//  assert(userDetails.displayName != null);
//  assert(userDetails.photoUrl != null);
//  name = userDetails.displayName;
//  email = userDetails.email;
//  imageUrl = userDetails.photoUrl;
//// Only taking the first part of the name, i.e., First Name
//  if (name.contains(" ")) {
//    name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" "));
//  }


  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
  await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `credentials` in your code is undefined, it should be like this:

```
Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
  print("signed in " + user.displayName);
  return user;
}
```

First get the `credentials` then add the variable as a parameter to `signinwithcredential`

---

Try the following:

```
Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  String name;
  String email;
  String imageUrl;

//  final FirebaseUser userDetails =
//  (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
//// Add the following lines after getting the user
//// Checking if email and name is null
//  assert(userDetails.email != null);
//  assert(userDetails.displayName != null);
//  assert(userDetails.photoUrl != null);
//  name = userDetails.displayName;
//  email = userDetails.email;
//  imageUrl = userDetails.photoUrl;
//// Only taking the first part of the name, i.e., First Name
//  if (name.contains(" ")) {
//    name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" "));
//  }


  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
  await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}
```

Comment: i have edited my post please kindly check is it the correct way i didn't understand how to do it

Comment: how can i do for once

Comment: there's some problem with a method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204799/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-myname).